# NameError: name 'msg' is not defined when I've clearly defined it in my code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I open a new file and try to run this simple code it's saying that "msg" isn't defined when in the screenshot, it clearly is being defined. I've made sure to save my code too.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MexDo.png)

Comment: run the python on file, currently you are running just terminal

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2):

You've started the Python REPL in the Terminal, and seem to be typing `print(msg)` directly there, where the variable has *not* been defined.

You are not running the Python *file* that is written above.

Start here - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python

> - In the text editor: right-click anywhere in the editor and select **Run Python File in Terminal**. If invoked on a selection, only that
>   selection is run.
> - In Explorer: right-click a Python file and select **Run Python File in Terminal**.

Comment: I see running python file in terminal works now but how come I get this when I just click run code normally: [Running] python -u "/Users/joonchoi/hello/hello.py"
/bin/sh: python: command not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.004 seconds

Comment: That error means `python` is not available on your OS PATH. `echo $PATH` in a terminal and look for `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not running the code. You directly wrote the print(msg) in the terminal instead of that click the run button(in triangle) at the top right side.
[image]

Comment: now its showing this in the output:[Running] python -u "/Users/joonchoi/hello/hello.py"
/bin/sh: python: command not found

Comment: Delete the terminal and try again.. If it's not working then it might be issue due to improperly installation of python or not setting the environment variable properly.